# How to insert timetable to mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store school timetable / class schedule to mysql database. Need help to understand. Here is php form

```
Period No.  Monday      Tuesday     Wednesday   Thursday    Friday      Saturday

1           Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject
            Classrrom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom

2           Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject
            Classrrom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom

3           Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject
            Classrrom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom

4           Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject
            Classrrom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom

5           Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject
            Classrrom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom

6           Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     
            Classrrom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom   

7           Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     
            Classrrom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom                                                                                
8           Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     Subject     
            Classrrom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom   Classroom
```

How can I insert this form to database or any other solution for this type school timetable. Need different subject and classroom for everyday and total period are 8. Please help me

Comment: When do you want us to finish your project?

Comment: I am sorry. Have i asked something wrong? :(

Comment: This form pretty much translates to a flat MySQL table really easily, alternatively you can house two tables, `weeks` and `subjects` with the subjects tables holding the classroom the subject is in linked via fk to a day row in the weeks table

Comment: Thank you Sammaye. I am trying to have table structure if you could help

Answer (score 1):

#### You can do the same way you asked.

```
CREATE TABLE timetable
    (`Period` int, `Monday` varchar(17), `Tuesday` varchar(17), `Wednesday` varchar(17), `Thursday` varchar(17), `Friday` varchar(17), `Saturday` varchar(17))
;

INSERT INTO timetable
    (`Period`, `Monday`, `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`, `Thursday`, `Friday`, `Saturday`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom'),
    (2, 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom'),
    (3, 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom'),
    (4, 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom'),
    (5, 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom'),
    (6, 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom'),
    (7, 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom'),
    (8, 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom', 'Subject-Classroom')
;
```

#### And you have the output this way:

```
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| PERIOD |            MONDAY |           TUESDAY |         WEDNESDAY |          THURSDAY |            FRIDAY |          SATURDAY |
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|      1 | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom |
|      2 | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom |
|      3 | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom |
|      4 | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom |
|      5 | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom |
|      6 | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom |
|      7 | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom |
|      8 | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom | Subject-Classroom |
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Now using **PHP**, you can parse it this way:

```
<?php
     $class = explode("-", $class);
     // Subject: $class[0];
     // Classroom: $class[1];
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Praveen, I just wondering how to manage in db. relation and table structure.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should create a db table with 4 fields: day, period, subject and classroom.
2. Create the form, naming elements something like "1-1-subject" for Monday first period and "3-5-subject" for wednesday 5th period.
3. Iterate through post values and save them to db, You can easily take field names apart with the PHP explode function.